# Fetching tweets between a specific time frame

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am trying to use the twittR package to fetch tweets between the 27th and 30th of august 2014. However, this:

```
tw <- searchTwitter("Obamacare", n = 10, lang= "en", since = "2014-08-27", until = "2014-08-30")
```

Does not seem to work. Any thoughts where I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not by using `searchTwitter`. Once again:

> The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an
>   index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9
>   days of Tweets.

([Source](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search))

The might be some [paid services](https://gnip.com/products/historical/search-api/) to help you with getting access to historic tweets.